# 99 Mustang Volt Gauge Issue

Tags: electrical, ford, mustang

I have a 99 Mustang 3.8 liter engine. Battery gauge was going down so I had the battery and alternator tested. Was told battery was bad and I replaced it. Same thing happened. I replaced the alternator next Two days later my wife started the car and the battery gauge went to minus symbol after a minute or two of engine running in driveway with heat on. Need some input here... What kind of electrical issue do I have? If any.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the voltage at the battery when this is going on? If not, pull out a multi-meter and see what the voltage is at the battery. It should read somewhere between 13-14vdc. Do this directly at your battery posts and not off on some other ground/power source. If your charging looks good, the issue, I think would point at the gauge being the issue. It is not unheard of for you to get a bad alternator, especially if it's a rebuilt one. Considering the car was still running when the gauge read like it did, I'm doubting there is a problem with your charging system, but you never know. Another indicator would be if the gauge was looking fine, then suddenly dropped over to the negative side. In order for the car to run, it needs electricity. If it had used up enough out of your battery to drop the gauge like that, the engine would die due to the lack.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that the wires on your starter are tight. Also a bad ground can cause that to happen. I experienced something very similar in my Ford pickup. It ended up being the starter relay. It was bad and dragging. This was causing a dead short. My headlights were dimming when I turned the heater on though. Also a also if the relay is going bad it will affect the gauges. Another problem I had once before was a bad ignition switch was causing a short. Try the cheapest first. It seems like you are  have something that is shorting pretty bad. Usually you can find a short just by looking to see if any wires have gotten hot. You can tell if the insulation is a little distorted in shape. Also the ends of the connections will be discoloured and will corrode faster then the others.  The first thing I would check though is to make sure your ground wire for the battery isn't corroded or lose on the end that grounds to the vehicle. Check to make sure your starter wires didn't come loose.